# A question on limit points and sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Suppose $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ satisfies $x_{n}>0$ for all $n,$ and $x$ is any limit point of the sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\} .$ When is $x>0 $?

My understanding is that we can assert that the limit point is positive $x>0 $ when (1) the sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$  is increasing (non-decreasing).

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Why do you require that there is only one limit point? Or rather, why do you think this is necessary?

Comment: If there are more than one limit points, then it is possible that for a sequence such as (-1)^k, the limit point will be either positive or negative. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It can be false if $x$ is the only limit point or one of many.. Decreasing counterexamples also exist.

Comment: Oh see, your (1) and (2) are two alternative hypothesis. Then what about $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: I see, (2) is clearly not a good hypothesis.

Comment: Why not just look directly at $\liminf_{k \to \infty} x_k$?

Comment: Just to be confusing: Every $n$ has a prime factorization. If $n=p_1^{k_1}*...*p_m^{k_m}$ the $x_k =\frac 1{p_1} + ... + \frac 1{p_m}$. Example. $x_2=\frac 12$ and $x_3=\frac 13;x_4=\frac 12; x_5=\frac 15;x_6=\frac 12+\frac 13=\frac 56;x_{30}=\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 15=\frac{31}{30}$ and so on. $0$ is a limit point (for any $\epsilon$ there are infinitely many primes, $p$ so that $x_p =\frac 1p < \epsilon.$  But $\frac 12$ is a limit point because there are infinitely many primes so taht $x_{2+p}=\frac 12+\frac 1p;|x_{p+2}-\frac 12|<\epsilon$. So monotone or single limit point don't matter.

Comment: Monotonicity doesn't matter because to be a limit point there must be an infinite number of $x_k$ terms in every neighborhood.  But they can be interspersed with gazillions of terms that are *not* in the neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a real valued sequence s.t. $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x_k > 0$ and an accumulation point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x > 0$ if and only if $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x_k > \varepsilon$ for some fixed $\varepsilon > 0$.

In this case we also know that $x \geq \varepsilon$.

This is in particular true when $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is non-decreasing (although it need not be bounded).

It is not sufficient that the accumulation point is unique though, as the example $(\frac{1}{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ shows.

Try showing the above characterization as well as the other comments.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still having difficulty understanding why $x_{k} > \epsilon$ for some fixed $\epsilon$ is an important condition if we already know that $x_{k} > 0$ for all $k$

Comment: Have a look at $(1/n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. This sequence converges to $0$ even though all of its terms are strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: I see, but would it be sufficient to require that the sequence is monotone (increasing or non-decreasing)? $(1/n)_{n \in N}$ is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: Seeing as $\frac 1n$ *is* decreasing and it has a limit point of $0$ then you *DON'T* want that to happen.  But *no* it is *not* enough to *disallow* monotone.  Take $x_k = \frac 1k$ if $k$ is odd but $x_k = k$ if $k$ is even.  That is not monotone but it has $0$ as a limit point.  Order doesn't matter.  What matter is that there are only a finite number of $x_k$ "close" to $0$.

Comment: @Lily Yes, if a sequence were monotone increasing (!), that would be enough, since then for $k \geq 1$ we have $x_k \geq x_1 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Why can say that $x>0$ iff $\exists r>0: \forall^\ast k \in \Bbb N: |x_k| \ge r$ (where $\forall^\ast$ is the quantor signifying for all most at most finitely many).

Both implications aren't hard.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition.  $x$ is a limit point if for every $\epsilon > 0$ then $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ will contain infinitely $x_k$.

So for $w$ not to be a limit point there must be some $\epsilon$ so that $(w-\epsilon, w+\epsilon)$ have at most a finite number of $x_k$.

If all $x_k > 0$ then no negative number, $w< 0$, can be a limit point.  For any $0 < \epsilon < |w|$  that neighbourhood $(w-\epsilon,w+\epsilon) \subset (-\infty, 0)$ and contains only negative points, so it does *not* contain an infinite number of $x_k > 0$.  It contains *not* $x_k> 0$.

Although all $x_k > 0$ that doesn't mean that the limit points are are positive.  $0$ is a  possible limit point. It could be that $(0, \epsilon) \subset (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ *will* always  have an infinite number of $x_k$ no matter how small $\epsilon$ is.

The only way to assure this *doesn't* happen is assuring that there is some $e > 0$ so that $(0,e)$ will only have *finitely* many $x_k$.

Or in other words all but a finite number of $x_k$ are larger than $e$ for some $e$.

But if *only* a finite number of $x_k < e$ then we can find the smallest of those, and let $e'$ be the smallest of those.  The is the same thing as saying *ALL* $x_k \ge e' > 0$.

So that is a more efficient condition:

If there is an $e'> 0$ so that all $x_k \ge e'$ then all limit points of $x_k$ are positive.

=======

The important thing to realize is that although $\{x_k\}$ might be bounded below and might have a greatest lower bound $\inf\{x_k\}$, that doesn't mean that any of the $x_i$ actually *equal* the $\inf \{x_k\}$.

It is possible that $x_i > \inf\{x_k\}$ for *ALL* $x_i$.  But if $M > \inf\{x_k\}$ there will be an *infinite* number of $x_i$ so that $M > x_i > \inf\{x_k\}$.

So another way of stating the above is:

All limit points of $\{x_k\}$ are positive if $\inf\{x_k\} > 0$.